# iPhone - Keyboard corner button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I would like to make an extra button in the iPhone keyboard left bottom corner like on the photo bellow. Is it possible to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to customize those buttons is to rebuild the keyboard itself.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial

Ray has always got some good tutorials on iphone dev. being able to customize your inputView is only half the battle tho. You will then need to build the custom view. Likely you will want to emulate the existing keypad, with your custom button obviously.

as a side note. to dismiss the keyboard you need to resignFirstResponder via the first responder.

When you get that far, here is the code I use to do exactly that

```
@implementation UIView (FindAndResignFirstResponder)
- (BOOL)findAndResignFirstResponder
{
    UIView *responder = [self findFirstResponder];
    if (responder) {
        [responder resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;     
    }
    return NO;
}
- (UIView*)findFirstResponder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {
        return self;     
    }
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        UIView *responder = [subView findFirstResponder];
        if (responder != nil)
            return responder;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

call the if you have a hold of the superview of all your inputs, you can call findAndResignFirstResponder on that view.

Or as you can see the findAndResignFirstResponder calls resignFirstResponder on the "found" firstResponder. therefore if you have the first responder you can just resign it

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. The Keyboard is owned by the system. You can change the kind of keyboard (normal, numeric, twitter etc), but you can't customise it. It is a question which is worth a +1

Comment: There are apps that seem to override this button.  I assume that the have either written a whole new keyboard view for it or somehow placed a button over the space where the button should be.

Comment: It is possible without to rewrite anything. You can iterate through the view hierarchy of the keyboard and change his buttons. The problem is, that this is an undocumented feature and there's a 50-50 chance that apple will reject it. It really depends on the reviewer and his mood. I've seen both.

Comment: That's right. And in a sense, everything is customisable. You just need to know what to do. But if you intend to be in the app store then it's highly recommended to not try to go under the hood in any sense.